# perl - how to convert hh:mm:ss to seconds

Tags: shell-script, scripting, perl

Is there a way in perl to convert a duration (hh:mm:ss) to total number of seconds?

sample: 02:50:30
output: 10230

Comment: The literal answer is "yes". What have you tried?

Comment: `split` the string on '`:`', multiply, add..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program should do it:

```
$hhmmss="02:50:30";
@arr=split(':',$hhmmss);
$sec=@arr[2];
$sec+=@arr[1]*60;
$sec+=@arr[0]*3600;
print $sec;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -le '$t=shift;
            ($h,$m,$s) = split /:/, $t;
            print $h * 3600 + $m * 60 + $s' 02:50:30
10230
```

or, the same without the $t variable:

```
$ perl -l -e '($h,$m,$s) = split /:/, shift;
              print $h * 3600 + $m * 60 + $s' 02:50:30
10230
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all the time unit with a regexp, then reference them back to do the math:

```
perl -e 'print $1*3600 + $2*60 + $3 if $ARGV[0]=~/^(\d{2,}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/' "02:50:30"
```